# IBM Engineering Requirements Management DOORS, inlinks disappear while deleting/moving modules

Tags: module, directory, project, subdirectory, ibm-doors

I have a module under 3 subfolders ,and I need to delete one folder. The problem is **after I delete a folder, inlinks disappear**.

Let me explain more clearly;
There are three folders named

```
-FolderA
   -FolderB
       -FolderC
```

and a module named
ModuleX

The location is;    **FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/ModuleX**

```
-FolderA
    -FolderB
        -FolderC
           -ModuleX
```

What I want to do is that I want to delete FolderC;    **FolderA/FolderB/ModuleX**

```
-FolderA
     -FolderB
         -ModuleX
```

When I do this I lost my all inlinks, is there any other way to fix this? Maybe DOORS options or DXL codes or any other things?

Thanks in advance.

There is only one way I've found which works out is to write a DXL code which creates links but it takes so much time. Is there any practical way?

Comment: please provide more information. If you move ModuleX from FolderC to FolderB, this should not invalidate any links going out of ModuleX to ModuleZ. Also, in ModuleZ, the links going in to ModuleZ should not be affected

Comment: Also: do I understand you correctly that all, Folder A, Folder B, Folder C, ,Module X and Module Z are contained in the same project?

Comment: yes, they are in the same project but in different folders.

Comment: @Mike in the first question you asked, The problem is in the first place ModuleX 's inlink path is FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/ModuleX    but when I delete FolderC,  the path becomes invalid now, because there is no FolderC.

When I rename a folder instead of deleting, everything is fine. There is no problem with that. However, when I delete a folder, it disappears the inlinks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inlink path" - where in DOORS would you see this?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused why you lose inlinks instead of outlinks.
Just an idea: Perhaps your link module was stored in FolderC. Link Modules are usually stored in the same folder as the formal module that contains the OUTgoing links - but perhaps you just have an unusual folder structure.

If your link module(s), (especially the one where definitions of the links going from formal ModuleZ to formal ModuleX module is contained) are stored in FolderC AND if you move ModuleX from FolderC to FolderB AND if you soft delete FolderC AND if you afterwards purge FolderC AND if you click "Yes" in the following dialog that says "The selection contains one or more Link modules. Purging will destroy all associated links. Are you sure you want to continue?", you might lose inlinks.

Currently I cannot think of any other situation where you might lose links upon deleting or purging a folder.